# Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost/') with script ('http://localhost/service-worker.js')

Tags: vue.js, progressive-web-apps, capacitor, vue-pwa

I am trying to convert my vue pwa project to a android project with [capacitor](https://capacitorjs.com/).

Here are the steps i followed.

First added pwa to my vue project and build it

```
vue add @vue/pwa
npm run build
```

At this point the app works as a pwa, having serviceworker and offline support.
Then I added capacitor and converted to android project

```
npm install --save @capacitor/core @capacitor/cli
npx cap init 
npx cap add android
npm run build
npx cap copy
npx cap open android
```

But when I run the android project i get the following errors

```
E/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/js/chunk-vendors.3815e007.js - Line 7 - Msg: TypeError: Cannot read property '-1' of undefined
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "An unknown error occurred when fetching the script.", source:  (0)
E/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/js/app.15b911b2.js - Line 1 - Msg: Error during service worker registration: TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost/') with script ('http://localhost/service-worker.js'): An unknown error occurred when fetching the script.
D/Capacitor: App paused
```

Here is the [console log](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/jGZcJnYHVB/)
I need to properly work serviceworker

EDIT: When i clicked `http://localhost/js/app.15b911b2.js` i found NOT FOUND. But if i add port to the link -
`http://localhost:8081/js/app.15b911b2.js` I can fetch the file. So im guessing if could make my project use the link with port the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Service workers won’t go through the capacitor requests so they fail to load.
You can add this code in `MainActivity.java` like this:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24 ){
  ServiceWorkerController swController = ServiceWorkerController.getInstance();

  swController.setServiceWorkerClient(new ServiceWorkerClient() {
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebResourceRequest request) {
      return bridge.getLocalServer().shouldInterceptRequest(request);
    }
  });
}
```

But notice that it requires SDK 24 and Capacitor supports SDK 21, so it won't work on 21-23

Answer (score 1):

This error fixed after changing hostname in capacitor.config.json file for my case.

Added config is here:

```
"server": {
    "hostname": "your_hostname_is_here"
}
```